# Question on integral manipulation

Tags: integration

Is my logic / math correct ?

We start with 
$$f(x,t) = {1 \over {\sqrt {2\pi } }}\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {(x{e^{\sigma z\sqrt t  - {1 \over 2}{\sigma ^2}t}} - k){e^{-{1 \over 2}{z^2}}}dz} $$

The integrand is strictly positive if $$z > {{\log \left( {{k \over x}} \right)} \over {\sigma \sqrt t }} + {1 \over 2}\sigma \sqrt t  \equiv {l_t}(x)$$

(this comes from $x{e^{\sigma z\sqrt t  - {1 \over 2}{\sigma ^2}t}} - k > 0$)

**IF $t \in (0,\infty )$, $x \in (0,\infty )$ , then we replace $$\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  { \to \int\limits_{{l_t}}^\infty  {} } $$ so ${{l_t}(x)}$ represents $0$ (or our lower bound)?**

Hence we arrive at $$f(x,t) = {x \over {\sqrt {2\pi } }}\int\limits_{{l_t}(x)}^\infty  {{e^{\sigma z\sqrt t  - {1 \over 2}{\sigma ^2}t - {1 \over 2}{z^2}}}dz}  - {k \over {\sqrt {2\pi } }}\int\limits_{{l_t}(x)}^\infty  {{e^{ - {1 \over 2}{z^2}}}} dz$$

update : Particularly, is the logic in **bold** correct?

Comment: The inequality for $z$ implicitly requires $x>0$ to hold (and $\sigma>0,t>0$ as well). Perhaps those assumptions should be declared earlier.

Comment: As to the question, the integration interval can be split at $l_t(x)$ and the integral can thereby be split in two summands, one negative, one positive. You keep only the positive part...

Comment: hmm...I don't understand this last point, I was unsure if one can change the lower bound of the integral and if it is correct to think about it in this way when I change the lower bound from ${ - \infty }$ to ${l_t}(x)$

Comment: You can change an integration interval bound if the interval thus added or removed contributes an integral of exactly zero. Is that the case here?

Comment: not sure i understand but the integral is not exactly zero

Comment: So basically your $f(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{l_t(x)}\cdots + \int_{l_t(x)}^\infty\cdots$, and the left integral is nonzero...

Comment: BTW, the integral over $(-\infty,\infty)$ can be evaluated in closed form. Why the hassle?

Comment: to your last points, honestly i dont know this problem is take from the following :  p.1 ) https://ibb.co/cjuvfk, p.2 )  https://ibb.co/kgk1Lk  i wanted to understand the procedure the author did till (4.62)

Comment: AH! You forgot the $(\ldots)^+$. That probably means "replace negative values with $0$".

Comment: that means the maximum(>0) or 0

Comment: That $(\ldots)^+$ is essential because it reduces the $\int_{-\infty}^{l_t(x)}(\ldots)^+$ to zero. Then your logic applies.

Comment: Yeah now i understand that the negative part is 0  thank you! that was the missing piece .But i still dont get why you have to split it into $$f(x,t) = \int\limits_{ - \infty }^{{l_t}(x)} {...}+ \int\limits_{{l_t}(x)}^\infty  {...} $$

Comment: Because this split allows you to replace the $(\ldots)^+$ with something you know. Left, its $0$; right, it's the $(\ldots)$.

Comment: (Remember, $z$ runs through those intervals.)

Comment: ah so your saying that $$f(x,t) = \int\limits_{ - \infty }^{{l_t}(x)} {...}+ \int\limits_{{l_t}(x)}^\infty  {...} $$ represents $$f(x,t) = \int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {...} $$ just in two parts?

Comment: Right (with a plus in between)

Comment: O k, got it !The first expression had the integral which was from - $\infty $ to +$\infty $ ,

Comment: But basically my thought process of "so ${{l_t}(x)}$represents $ 0 $ was right?

Comment: No. (At least it does not represent $z=0$.) It's just that the interval of integration has been reduced to the range where the integrand $(\ldots)^+$ is nonzero, that is, where the $(\ldots)>0$.

Comment: Your first expression must be $f(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty(\ldots)^+dz$. With that $(\ldots)^+$ there and in a few following places, the exposition makes sense. Without the $(\ldots)^+$, one could directly evaluate $f(x,t)=x-k$ and wonder what this all is about.

Comment: [Related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/812199/75794).